# Bootstrap flex place text at bottom

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place text at the bottom of the image but it's placed at side of the image

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card">
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-4">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <h4>A</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-4">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <h4>B</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using semantic HTML with `text-center` class:

```
<figure>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <figcaption class="text-center">B</figcaption>
</figure>
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-4">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <figure>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <figcaption class="text-center">A</figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-4">

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <figure>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
            <figcaption class="text-center">B</figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```